# Adding an object to a dropdown list without reloading the page

Tags: ajax, django

Hi I have a 'member' model that references a 'role' model. What I would like is when a user creates a 'member' they can either choose from a list of default 'roles' (that have been loaded to the database when the server starts using fixtures) or they can click on add role and then type in and click submit and the newly created role is created and assigned to the newly created 'member' object.

I would like it so that I am able to just create a role without submitting, and the role then appears in the dropdown menu for the role field in the member model. Is this where I would need to learn about AJAX to implement this feature?

**Models**

```
class MemberRole(models.Model,get_fields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

class Member(models.Model,get_fields):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    role = models.ForeignKey(MemberRole, null = True, blank = True)
```

**View**

```
def add_member(request):

    model_url = 'member-add'

    if request.method == "POST":
        rform = MemberRoleForm(request.POST, instance=MemberRole())
        mform = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=Member())
        if rform.is_valid() and mform.is_valid():
            new_role = rform.save()
            new_member = mform.save(commit=False)
            new_member.role = new_role
            new_member.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('members')
    else:
        rform = MemberRoleForm(instance=MemberRole())
        mform = MemberForm(instance=Member())
    return render_to_response('create_model.html', {'role_form': rform, 'member_form': mform, 'model_url': model_url,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**snippet create_model.html**

```
<div id = "subtemplate">
<form action="{% url model_url %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% if model_url == 'member-add' %}

    {% for field in member_form %}
    {% if field.label == 'Role' %}
        <div id="roleExistsMemberForm">
            <button type="button" onclick="showDiv()">Add Role</button>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} {{ field.help_text }}
        </div>

    {% else %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
    <div Id="addRoleOnMemberForm">
    {% for field in role_form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

  {% else %}

  <ul>
    <li>{{ form.as_ul }}</li>
  </ul>

  {% endif %}
    <div id="centerbuttons">
        <input id="save_contact" type="submit" value="Add"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Ajax would be the first point of call for something like this. You can submit the form in the background to a Django view, the view could then respond with a fresh list of options to re-populate the drop down list with.